# VSTS Release Phase Condition Based Off From One of Many Builds

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

First attempt at automated build and continuous deployment so any process suggestions / improvements are welcome.

I have a repository with different build definitions.  One for each of the following:  database project, api, and web.  (Will add more later for etl / reports)  Each build has a filter so it only builds if code in a specific path has been changed.

Currently I have separate releases using continuous deployment for each build.  So when the code changes, it builds that auto deploys. This works, but really isn't practical because of dependencies.

What I am looking to do is have one release definition that includes all build artifacts.  Then have deployment phases that only run conditionally if a specific build artifact was created (something in that project changed). This way all builds / releases don't run every time, but are tied together when there are related changes.

[image: Pipeline]

I am going down the path of trying to created a custom condition on the deployment phase, but can't seem to figure out a way to make this work.  I appreciate any help with this.

[image: VSTS Deployment Phase]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a repository with different build definitions. One for each of
>   the following: database project, api, and web. (Will add more later
>   for etl / reports) Each build has a filter so it only builds if code
>   in a specific path has been changed

Path filters are not to be used in your situation.

If you see [Microsoft's git repo](https://www.visualstudio.com/learn/use-git-microsoft/),

They have all their codebase from the Windows and Devices Group (WDG) in one big repo. Each root folder is a separate product and completely unrelated to the rest. (eg. Xbox, HoloLens, Windows OS, etc).

**Path filters makes sense here because if I git push code to Xbox, I don't want Hololens code also to be built.**

---

**Web / DB / API projects all need to be built together, packaged together and deployed together.**

I am assuming the project uses .NET stack.

Keep the DB, Web and API projects are in the same solution. Create a single build definition that builds the solution and create multiple artifacts(dacpac, webdeploy package etc.) **by adding multiple publish artifacts step**.

See screenshot of a build with multiple artifacts.

[image: Sample build definition with multiple artifacts]

Link the artifacts from this build to the Release Definition and you should be able to deploy.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I was over thinking this.  My initial intent was not to run the database publish or api if there was just a simple html change.  But I your solution is just cleaner and easier to deploy them all together.